How to add a nested list of strings to isar database in Flutter
I am trying to add a nested list of strings to an isar database, but I'm getting an Unsupported type error when trying to define the schema.
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@Collection()
class User{
  Id? id;
  late String name;
  late String email;
  List<List<String>>? history;
  @Index()
  late String phone;
}

I tried creating a class with the embedded tag, but got the same error. Is there anyway to get around this?

As per Isar Documentation, Isar supports List but no List of List.
You can create nested embedded objects as for instance:
@Collection()
class User{
  Id? id;
  late String name;
  late String email;
  List<HistoryList>? historyList;
  late String phone;
}


@embedded
class HistoryList {
  List<String>? elements;
}

